# Getting "selenium manager does not exist in the current context" error while writing command in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, g1ant

selenium manager does not exist in the current context, even i have also install selenium web driver packages also.But still I am facing this issue

C# Code: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8t8yx.png

Answer (score 0):

To counter your problem, follow these steps:

1. Ensure that you have replaced selenium to your application name. Double-check the same for each API and Variables.
2. Download the necessary drivers and set certain aspects such as G1ANT.Language version from true to false.
   These steps worked for me to counter the Selenium.Settings error in Visual Studio.